# Debezium Postgres and ElasticSearch - Store complex Object in ElasticSearch

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, debezium

I have in Postgres a database with a table "product" which is connected 1 to n with "sales_Channel". So 1 Product can have multiple SalesChannel. Now I want to transfer it to ES and keep it up to date, so I am using debezium and kafka. It is no problem to transfer the single tables to ES. I can query for SalesChannels and Products. But I need Products with all SalesChannels attached as a Result. How get I debezium to transfer this?

mapping for Product

```
    {
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

sink for Product

```
   {
  "name": "es-sink-product",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "product",
    "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
    "transforms": "unwrap,key",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.deletes": "false",
    "transforms.key.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.key.field": "id",
    "key.ignore": "false",
    "type.name": "_doc",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "delete"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you either need to use Outbox pattern, see https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/configuration/outbox-event-router.html

or you can use aggregate objects, see
https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/jpa-aggregations
https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/kstreams-fk-join